# Rails remove user during set date to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to send a user off to "vacation". I want him to dissapear from my list when the start date is and come back on the end date.

I wrote this in my model but it doesn't behave.
anything that comes after "vacation" stops working.
( the arrows may be incorrect, but it's not what's causing the error )

```
def self.vacation
  if
    where("vacation_start >= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  else
    where("vacation_end <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  end
end
```

i.e `@posts = Post.all.vacation.`
in this instance, each stops working and it gets a 
`undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

Do I have incorrect syntax or something that makes this error or am I just barking up the wrong tree with this?

Edit:
as Athar mentioned, it may have been incorrectly written. as far as I understand, this should be correct

```
def self.vacation(vacation)
  if vacation
    where("vacation_start <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  else
    all
  end
```

end

but then I get "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Edit 2:

Trying to simplify what I'm asking for.

I want to do @posts = Post.where("vacation_start <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')). When it returns true, it displays the Posts that it concerns. that works as intended, but what I want is when it returns false. I then want him to check against the vacation_end instead (i.e my other where statement)

Solution:

```
def self.vacation
  posts = self.where("vacation_start > ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  return posts if posts.length > 0
  return self.where("vacation_end < ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
end
```

Using  Athar's solution, but removed the "=" signs to get my desired effect.

Thanks everyone!

Edit:
came up with a better solution.

```
.where.not('vacation_start <= ? AND vacation_end >= ?', Time.now, Time.now)
```

the previous solution didn't seem to work fully under heavy testing.

Comment: please can you share what is your if condition.? it wont work unless there is some if condition.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am confused. isn't the  first "where" line, the if in this case?

Comment: no, the first where line and the second where is the return statement. you have to add some condition after if that gets meet and where statement is returned.
 you should do something like this. 
if #condition and in next line
return  where("vacation_start >= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) else
 return where("vacation_end <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
end

Comment: Please have a look at this.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm

Comment: def self.vacation(vacation)
      if vacation
        where("vacation_start <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
      else
        all
      end
end

as far as I understand, this should be correct, but then I  "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Comment: so the issue is now that you are expecting vacation parameter in vacation method but from where you are calling it. Post.all.vacation. you are not sending vacation as parameter. Then the other issue. you cannot call vacation method after Post.all. You should do Post.vacation(#vacation what ever is parameter)  and in the method else condition you should return self.all

Comment: can you rephrase what you are trying to achieve and i will be glad to you help you in that.?

Comment: I've updated the main post

Comment: let me put the answer in code as answers. hope it shall work.

Comment: Just for information you need equal to condition with one of your where condition because if some one vacation_start date is equal to Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') current conditions might loose those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your method should be like this

```
def self.vacation
  posts = self.where("vacation_start >= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
  return posts if posts.length > 0
  return self.where("vacation_end <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
end
```

you should call this like

```
  Post.vacation
```

Comment: I hope this will work. if you want that if posts are still empty after vacation_end as well. repeat the process like what is did for vacation_start and if still length is not greater than 0, return self.all.

Comment: I think that does it! thank you so much sir. I would not have figured that out on my own.

1000 Thanks!

Comment: after some more testing. it doesn't seem to fully work. if vacation_start is set to an earlierdate than today, it goes away as expected. but if vacation_end is set to an ealier date than today, it doesn't return. it seems like only the first where statement is being run

Comment: im sorry your updated question statement show vacation_start  <= ?", Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), shall it be >=. is this the problem.?

Comment: updated my answer as well. actually both conditions were same. silly me